# How do I evaluate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log\left ( 1+\frac{k}{n^{2}} \right )$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, logarithms

My attempt :

$$\begin{align} S &=  \sum_{k=1}^{n} \log\left(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\right)\\ 
&= \log\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n} 1 + \frac{k}{n^2}\right) \\
&= \log\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n^2 + k}{n^2}\right)\\
&= \log\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\prod_{k=1}^{n} {n^2 + k}\right) \end{align}$$

How can I take it from here? 
Any Suggestions?

Comment: Leave it in the sum form, and use $\log (1+x) = x + O(x^2)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Already tried doing that, didn't help much.

Comment: @KDBoi: You get $$...=\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{k}{n}+\mathcal O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{k^2}{n^2}\right).$$ The first term goes to $\int_0^1 xdx$ and the $\mathcal O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{k^2}{n^2}\right)=o(1)$. At the end, you get $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**. An elementary way is to use the inequality
$$
x-\frac{x^2}2 \le \ln(1+x)\le x,\qquad0\le x \le1,
$$ giving
$$
\frac{k}{n^2}-\frac{k^2}{2n^4} \le \ln \left( 1 +\frac{k}{n^2}\right)\le \frac{k}{n^2},\qquad0\le k \le n,
$$ then one may conclude with
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac{n(n+1)}2
$$ and the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Worked smoothly. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 5):

We have $$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{k}{n^{2}}\right)=\frac{1}{n^{2n}}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(n^{2}+k\right)=\frac{\left(n^{2}+1\right)_{n}}{n^{2n}}$$ where $\left(x\right)_{m}$ is the [Pochhammer symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html) and since $$\left(x\right)_{m}=\frac{\Gamma\left(x+m\right)}{\Gamma\left(x\right)}$$ we have $$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{k}{n^{2}}\right)=\frac{\Gamma\left(n^{2}+n+1\right)}{n^{2n}\Gamma\left(n^{2}+1\right)}\rightarrow\color{red}{\sqrt{e}}$$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, by [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that for $x>0$,
$$x-\frac{x^2}{2} <\log(1+x)<x.$$

Answer (score 1):

[image]Multiply n square on both sides then put it in the log,u will get a limit for e,after simplifying everything you should be getting half

Comment: Sorry,don't know matlab

Comment: [Here's a mathjax tutorial :)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)